# Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I'm trying to render a component from an object, but the code is failing with an error:

```
const Login = () => <>login</>

const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: Login
  }
]

function AppRouter() {
  return <Routes>
      {publicRoutes.map(({path, component}) => (
        <Route path={path} component={component} /> // warning
      ))}
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since version 6, React Router Dom no longer takes components, but elements instead. [<sup>[react-router-dom]</sup>](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element)
So instead of passing component you need to pass `<Component/>` like this:

```js
{publicRoutes.map(({path, component: Component}) => (
  <Route path={path} element={<Component/>} /> // no warning
))}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! what means `component: Component`?

Comment: this is called destructuring, it works like this : `const {a: varName} = {a: 3}` here `varName` gets the `3` value. In your example you are storing components under component key, so to get the component you access it by the `component:` part then the name of variable is `Component`, in JSX the component name should be Capitalized to not be treated as a normal HTML tag

Comment: {path, Component} is also working correctly
but now I can't understand what means your code above - `component: Component`
is it just renaming of object key?

Comment: yes, since you where using `component: Login`, I didn't touch that configuration, so if you use `{path, Component}` you need to write `Component: Login`

Comment: I'm getting `JSX element type 'LoadingMoreComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.` when I do this

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TS and getting this type of errors in 2023/2024, just keep in mind that it can be relate to tsconfig!

In my case i got it for two different projects, and solutions looked like this:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  }
```

or

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es2021"
  },
```

Play with `tsconfig.json` options and I hope this helps you, because I spent a ton of time before that error, that doesn't make any sense, led to to this article that helpend me to find the source of the issue

Credits to: [Some random blog from page 4 of Google search](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2023/06/30/react-types-reactnode-error/)

Comment: Any difference for NextJS?

Comment: Ts config/compiler is agnostic to your front framework. You might encounter same issue with astro, vue, angular etc.

Comment: The first one fixed it for me. Using NextJS.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @697 basically helped me, with a minor amendment:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  }
```